# Java cucumber - java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: gherkin.parser.Parser.parse

Tags: java, cucumber, gherkin, prettyfaces, cucumber-junit

Trying to implement cucumber to do some automated tests. When I run my tests using junit I am getting below error

**Project path:**

```
src/test/java/

cucumberJava
 -cucumberjava,java
 -runtest.java
 -cucumberJava.feature
```

**Runtest.java code**

package cucumberJava;

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith; 
import cucumber.junit.Cucumber; 
@RunWith(Cucumber.class) 
@Cucumber.Options(format={"pretty", "html:target/cucumber"})
public class runTest { }
```

**Error trace:**

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: gherkin.parser.Parser.parse(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;I)V
    at cucumber.runtime.FeatureBuilder.parse(FeatureBuilder.java:112)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberFeature.load(CucumberFeature.java:40)
    at cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptions.cucumberFeatures(RuntimeOptions.java:82)
    at cucumber.junit.Cucumber.<init>(Cucumber.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:33)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.<init>(JUnit4TestReference.java:33)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestClassReference.<init>(JUnit4TestClassReference.java:25)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Comment: You compiled against one version of the library but a different version is on the execution classpath.

Answer (score 1):

If you use maven, add this dependancy:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
    <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.3</version>
</dependency>
```